# How to handle the "Accpet cookies" pop up in Selenium (python)?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing a website using Selenium, and I am straggling to click on "Accpet cookies" that pops up after the website is loaded.

### Code:

```py
chromedriver_path = "C:\Dev\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"

service = Service(chromedriver_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get(URL)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//\*\[@id="uc-center-container"\]/div\[2\]/div/div/div/div/button\[2\]'))).click()
```

### Versions:

I am using :

- Python 3.10
- Selemium : 4.6.1
- Chromedriver: 108.0.5359

The element is not found, and the `TimeoutExecption` is thrown by Selemium.
When the website loads, the content is also loaded but does not contain the "Accept cookies" button (that loads afterwards), so I am expecting the following line to wait until that element is loaded

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="uc-center-container"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/button[2]'))).click()
```

but I am getting the `TimeoutException` instead.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue ?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: what is the url tho?

Comment: I was testing with `https://www.dm.de/`

Comment: button is under the shadow-dom handle that first